# Tailwind responsive small screen property overridden by sm: - max width

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I  am trying to create a responsive grid layout in `tailwind CSS` with one column on small screen size, and two columns on everything else. And I set the grid to have max-width so that the grid element has a max-width. However, `'max-w-md'` is is overridden by `'sm:max-w-6xl'` on small screen size. Am I missing anything or is there a workaround? See code and screenshots below:

```html
        <main class='container mx-auto'>
            <div class='grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 max-w-md mx-auto sm:grid-cols-2 max-w-6xl'>
                <div class='h-60 bg-red-100'>1</div>
                <div class='bg-red-200'>2</div>
                <div class='bg-red-100'>3</div>
                <div class='bg-red-200'>4</div>
                <div class='bg-red-200'>5</div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

[Small Screen Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Lva.png)
[Medium Screen Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLUh.png)

As shown on screenshots, the `'grid-cols'` properties work fine with breakpoints but the `'max-w'` do not.

Comment: There's no `sm:max-w-6xl` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`max-w-md` will be active till the width reaches `639px`. After this point `sm:grid-cols-2` will be active from `640px to 767px`

> responsive grid layout in tailwind css with one column on small screen size, and two columns on everything else

In such case, I suggest to use `md:grid-cols-2` instead. It triggers at `768px`

```
class='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4 max-w-md md:max-w-6xl mx-auto'
```